# Solve congruence

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Solve:$$ \underbrace{2 ^ {2 ^ { {...} ^ 2 }}}_\text{2016} \pmod {2016}$$

So $ 2016 = 2^5 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7$

And $$ \underbrace{2 ^ {2 ^ { {...} ^ 2 }}}_\text{2016} \pmod{2^5} \rightarrow \underbrace{2 ^ {2 ^ { {...} ^ 2 }}}_\text{2016} \pmod{2016} $$

$$ \underbrace{2 ^ {2 ^ { {...} ^ 2 }}}_\text{2016} \pmod{3^2} \rightarrow \underbrace{2 ^ {2 ^ { {...} ^ 2 }}}_\text{2016} \pmod{2016} $$

$$ \underbrace{2 ^ {2 ^ { {...} ^ 2 }}}_\text{2016} \pmod 7 \rightarrow \underbrace{2 ^ {2 ^ { {...} ^ 2 }}}_\text{2016} \pmod{2016} $$

What now?

Comment: Hint: Euler's Theorem

Comment: _Knuth's up-arrow notation_ is notationally handy here: $$ 2\Uparrow n = \underbrace{2^{2^{\cdots^2}}}_n $$

Comment: **Hint:** Exploit the fact that $\varphi(\varphi(\varphi(2016)))=2^6$, hence $\varphi^{(9)}(2016)=1$ ensures that the sequence $\pmod{2016}$ is constant for $n\geq 10$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I only know the notation $2\uparrow\uparrow n$. Where did you find the notation you mentioned ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda-function : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function

helps us to find a quick answer. Because of $\lambda(2016)=24$ and considering $2016=2^5\cdot 3^2\cdot 7$, we can conclude $a^k=a^{k+m\cdot 24}$ for all $a$ and $m$, when $k\ge 5$.

The given number can be written by $2^M$, where $M$ is a power tower of $2's$ with height $2015$. Obviously , $M$ is divisble by $8$ and the remainder modulo $3$ is $1$.

Applying the chinese remainde theorem , we get $M=16$ modulo $24$.

So, we can conclude $2^M=2^{16}=1024$ modulo $2016$.

Another approach :

The given number is obviously divisble by $2^5$. With induction, you can prove that $2^{2^m}=7$ modulo $9$ for every even $m\ge 2$.

The base case $m=2$ is easy to verify.
Then , $2^{2^{m+2}}=(2^{2^m})^4=7^4=7$ mod $9$ is the induction step.

Finally, you can show $2^{2^m}=2$ modulo $7$ for every even $m\ge 2$ analogue to the proof for $9$ (I will leave it to you as an exercise).

So, your number is congruent

$0$ modulo $32$

$7$ modulo $9$

$2$ modulo $7$

Now, apply the chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: I decided to make a new answer rather then editing my other answer because I overlooked that we need the Carmichael-function.

Comment: Would be helpful if you write how the initial equation changes step by step.

Comment: Would you prefer an answer without the carmichael-function ?

Comment: yes. I think we can just look up what are the reminders (mod 3) and (mod 7) and (mod 2) and then just go with the CRT. ?

Comment: I just edited my answer to show you a proof without the lambda-function. You only need induction and CRT. Hope, this is helpful.

Comment: The second approach shows even more : $2\uparrow\uparrow k=1024$ modulo $2016$ for every $k\ge 4$ as stated in the deleted answer. $2\uparrow\uparrow k$ stands for a power tower of $2's$ and height $k$. In this notation, the given number is $2\uparrow\uparrow 2016$

Comment: It seems to me  your answer is wrong. Examine it in order to edit maybe. If I am wrong I apologize. TeX Commands prevented me from putting my different solution . Tomorrow I write it. Best regards.

Comment: Note that the power tower is calculated from the top to the bottom. So, $2^{2^{2^2}}$ is NOT $({{(2^2)}^2})^2$ , but $2^{(2^{(2^2))}}$. So, for example $2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}$ is $2^{65536}$ and not $65536$.

Comment: @Peter: I see now. I have misunderstood the problem and calculated $2^{2016}$ modulo $2016$ which gave me $64$. I apologize. And I thank you your comment because I wanted to post my bad answer ( It was not a matter of editing your answer from me).